# Gitlab-ci-Runner- Stuck

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to this but I noticed that when I run a job and, let’s say, there is an error or something went wrong and the job is stuck at “Running” state, when I cancel it and try to restart the job, nothing is happening. I am attaching you a picture and also the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in order to see what I am doing. Please bear in mind that I just created a simple project in Angular 4 and I just trying to run the tests.

Here is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` code:

```yaml
image: node:4.2.2
before_script:
- npm install
stages:
- test
test_app:
stage: test
script:
- node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js
```

And here is what is happening after I cancel the job and retry to run it again. The runner is stuck:

[image]

My runner:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info about your Gitlab instance and connected runners? (Hosted, on-prem, dedicated runners, shared runners?)

Answer for as far as I can see: It looks like there is no runner available to run your jobs.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. This is what i have understand too. But i cancelled the job that is stuck and try to rerun it and nothing is happening. When you cancel the job the runner is not becoming available? I will also add a screenshot of the runner

Comment: Try replacing your `...karma start` command with an `echo 'In script block` and see if that helps, if it doesn't try to do the same with your `before_script`. This way you can pinpoint the exact issue.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't even read the .gitlab-ci.yml the second time